# Spark DataFrame casting string to date results in null values

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I get `null` when I attempt to cast string date in Spark DataFrame to `date` type.

```
# Create a list of data
data = [(1, "20230517"), (2, "20230518"), (3, "20230519"), (4, "null")]

# Create a DataFrame from the list of data
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("id", "date"))

df.show()


df.printSchema()

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)


# Convert the SaleDate column to datetime format
df1 = df.withColumn("date", df.date.cast('date'))
df1.select('date').show()

+--------+
|date    |
+--------+
|    null|
|    null|
|    null|
|    null|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this operation you should use `F.to_date()` and specify the format which you want to parse (`yyyyMMdd` in your case):

```
F.to_date('date', format='yyyyMMdd')
```

Full code I used:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('spark_session').getOrCreate()

# Create a list of data
data = [(1, "20230517"), (2, "20230518"), (3, "20230519"), (4, "null")]

# Create a DataFrame from the list of data
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("id", "date"))

# Convert the SaleDate column to datetime format
df1 = df.withColumn("date", F.to_date('date', format='yyyyMMdd'))
df1.select('date').show()

+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|2023-05-17|
|2023-05-18|
|2023-05-19|
|      null|
+----------+
```